# Can you make a number in a list/cell your index in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Basically, lets say I have a list of random numbers: `x = {3,5,6,7,8,11,13,14,16,22,25}`.
I want to loop through these numbers but I want my index to actually be each of the numbers. So if I did:

```
for i = x{1} : x{length(x)}

    disp(i);
```

I want my `i` to be `3`, then `5`, then `6`, `7`, `8`, `11`, `13` etc. ...
Basically I want to the difference between the next number and the current number and have that be my step.

Comment: Indeed, likely a duplicate. I would add however that for safety's sake it is better to use explicit indexing rather than relying on the 'for each' behaviour, which requires a specific orientation of the data. Normally this requirement would be fine, but the orientation produced by certain inbuilt matlab functions has changed in recent versions (e.g.: union, setdiff, etc.) and can break existing code.

Comment: @Alan You can force column orientation using the `colon` operator (`:`) or using `reshape`.

Comment: @EitanT Yes, my point being that you should either enforce orientation using the method you suggested, or make the orientation irrelevant, as you cannot trust that the orientation will reliably be what you expect.

Comment: @Alan Obviously... but that doesn't have anything to do with "explicit indexing".

Comment: @EitanT if you use `for i = 1:length(x), n = x(i)` rather than `for n = x` then it does not matter whether x is a column or a row. (That being what I meant by explicitly indexing).

Comment: @Alan Ah, okay. And probably JIT accelerates much better loops that iterate over incremental indices.

Comment: Do you realize that is you had x = [3 5 6 7 8...]; you could just go for i=x, disp(i); end  ?

Answer (score 2):

Since your list is in a cell you can use

```
for idx = cell2mat(x)
    disp(idx) 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if what you are looking for exists in matlab. I will do this:

```
for j = 1:x{size(x,2)}
  disp(x{j}); % or any other processing,
  % % you can also set i=x{j} and do what you wanted to do with i.
end
```

Answer (score -1):

For a vector `x`, if you want to create a new vector `result`, where the `ith` element of `result` is the `x(i)th` element of `x`, then you could use:

```
result = x(x);
```

This is equivalent to:

```
result = zeros(length(x));
for i = 1:numel(x)
    index = x(i);
    result(i) = x(index);
end
```

But it should be a heck of a lot faster. This may be useful for vectorizing your code and making it run faster. If you need to loop through the elements however (and it is best to avoid loops in MATLAB wherever possible), you could use:

```
for i = 1:numel(x)
    disp(x(x(i)))
end
```

Which is a little convoluted, but works.

A caveat: you have to make sure that none of the elements of `x` exceed the dimensions of `x`, otherwise you will get an error. Also, each element of `x` has to be an integer.

**EDIT:** This above method is for a vector, which is how I originally interpreted your question. For a cell array, it looks like your options are a bit more limited. I have not been able to find a faster way of doing this than using:

```
index = zeros(numel(x),1);
for i = 1:numel(x)
    index(i) = x{i};
end
```

This has been covered before. I am leaving my answer for now in case you do want the vector stuff at the beginning.

Comment: -1: `x(x)` makes no sense.

Comment: Except that it answers his question. Read my update please, which should clarify what `x(x)` is doing.

Comment: I've read your update, and from what I infer from the question, it's still far from what the OP wants to do. What you do here is use the values of `x` as indices, which lacks any meaning. And even if it did make sense, `x` is a cell array in this awkward example, so this would trigger a syntax error. Have a look at the links to the duplicate questions I've posted and Mohsen's answer.

Comment: Ah, cell arrays. I missed the curly brackets. Touche.